# Como mostrar un bottomNavigationBar con IndexedStack en una clase derivada de una vista

Tags: flutter, dart

Hola no se como hacer que este presente mi `bottomNavigationBar` en una clase derivada de una de las vistas de mi `bottomNavigationBar`.

Video demostracion:[VIDEO](https://recordit.co/1KYJV8Dyyl)

Como visteis al darle al boton de test me lleva a un segundo menu (hay figura el bottom bar por que tengo uno (usando pushReplacedname, para poder verse el ejemplo)), lo que busco es que en esa vista derivada haya el `bottomNavigationBar` y me lleve a las mimas paginas que especifique en `bottomNavigationBar` de main.dart.

Muestro de forma gráfica lo que quiero, en negro lo que tengo actualmente, en azul lo que quiero y lo que quiero que haga.

En `main.dart` tendria a menu como seleccion inicial.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:fancy_bottom_navigation/fancy_bottom_navigation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reactions/src/ui/estadisticas/estatidisticas.dart';
import 'package:reactions/src/ui/menus/principal.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:reactions/src/funcions/main_highscores.dart';
import 'package:reactions/src/ui/opciones.dart';

void main() => runApp(Reactions());

class Reactions extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Reactions createState() => _Reactions();
}

class _Reactions extends State<Reactions> {
  MainHighscores mainHighscores;

  void initState() {
    mainHighscores = MainHighscores();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<MainHighscores>.value(
        value: mainHighscores,
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Reactions',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          routes: {
            '/estadisticas': (context) => Estadisticas(),
            '/home': (context) => MenuPrincipal(),
            '/opciones': (context) => Opciones(),
          },
          theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Asap'),
          home: Inicio(),
        ));
  }
}

class Inicio extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _Inicio();
  }
}

class _Inicio extends State<Inicio> {
  int currentPage = 1;
  final _children = <Widget>[
    Estadisticas(),
    MenuPrincipal(),
    Opciones(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       body: IndexedStack(
         index: currentPage,
         children: _children,
       ),

      bottomNavigationBar: FancyBottomNavigation(
          initialSelection: 1,
          inactiveIconColor: Colors.black,
          textColor: Colors.black, // new
          tabs: [
            TabData(
              iconData: Icons.timeline,
              title: "Estadísticas",
            ),
            TabData(
              iconData: Icons.flash_on,
              title: "Inicio",
            ),
            TabData(
              iconData: Icons.settings,
              title: "Ajustes",
            ),
          ],
          onTabChangedListener: (int position) async {
            {
              setState(() {
                currentPage = position;
              });
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

**Clase derivada (MenuSecundario.dart)**

```
import 'package:fancy_bottom_navigation/fancy_bottom_navigation.dart';
import 'package:reactions/src/models/tipos_modos.dart';
import 'package:reactions/src/ui/juego/dos_jugadores.dart';
import 'package:reactions/src/ui/juego/un_jugador.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:swipeable_page_route/swipeable_page_route.dart';

class MenuSecundario extends StatefulWidget {
  final TiposModos tipo;
  MenuSecundario(this.tipo, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MenuSecundarioState createState() => _MenuSecundarioState();
}

class _MenuSecundarioState extends State<MenuSecundario> {
  final PageController viewController =
      PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8, initialPage: 0);

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          image: new DecorationImage(
            image: new AssetImage("assets/fondo_reactions.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 4, color: Colors.white),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                        ),
                        child: ButtonTheme(
                          height: 60,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            elevation: 12,
                            splashColor: Colors.blue,
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(SwipeablePageRoute(
                                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    UnJugador(widget.tipo),
                              ));
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              '1 Jugador',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 40,
                                color: Colors.yellow,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.75),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 4, color: Colors.white),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                        ),
                        child: ButtonTheme(
                          height: 60,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            elevation: 12,
                            splashColor: Colors.blue,
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(SwipeablePageRoute(
                                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    DosJugadores(widget.tipo),
                              ));
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              '2 Jugadores',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 40,
                                color: Colors.yellow,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
            )),
      ),
     
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: no se entiende muy bien lo que quieres lograr, sería mejor si lo graficas y pones una imagen de como sería el flujo que deseas

Comment: lo he editado, por favor echale un ojo, gracias por las molestias

Comment: el menu de abajo siempre será el mismo para todas las pantallas?

Comment: si es así, revisa esto, https://medium.com/flutter-community/add-a-tab-bar-and-navigation-bar-with-ios-style-in-your-next-flutter-app-bf97b1e27e3a

Comment: solo para la primera pantalla(menu principal) y segunda pantalla (a la que accedo mediate el boton) y las pantallas a las que llevan las opciones de bottombar.

El menu secundario tiene tambien botones pero las pantallas a las que dirige no quiero que tengan bottomNavBar

Comment: segun tu grafico, cuando presionas un botón del nav bar de el menu secundario te retorna a una pantalla q tiene los botones abajo

Comment: exacto, el menu secundario no pertenece a ninguna de las pantallas de los botones de abajo pero si que posee el bottombar para poder ir a dichas pantallas

Comment: ok, voy a preparar un ejemplo

Answer (score 2):

Ok, para poder ayudarte tuve que reducir el escenario a algo más sencillo, que creo yo es como lo deberías plantear.

Primero trabajar en la estructura y luego en los detalles.

**Pantalla principal**

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  void navigateToSecondaryMenu() async {
    final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => SecondaryMenu(),
      ),
    );

    if (result != null) {
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = result;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3796F0),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _currentIndex,
        children: [
          Screen1(
            onTap: navigateToSecondaryMenu,
          ),
          Screen2(),
          Screen3(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _MyNavigationBar(
        onItemSelected: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Barra de navegación**

```dart
class _MyNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueChanged<int> onItemSelected;

  const _MyNavigationBar({Key key, this.onItemSelected}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add_alert), onPressed: () => onItemSelected(0)),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.beenhere), onPressed: () => onItemSelected(1)),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.category), onPressed: () => onItemSelected(2)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Pantallas 1,2,3 iniciales**

```dart
class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  const Screen1({Key key, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: onTap,
        child: Text('Click here'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
    );
  }
}

class Screen3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
    );
  }
}
```

**Pantalla del menu secundario**

```dart
class SecondaryMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('hello secondary menu'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _MyNavigationBar(
        onItemSelected: (index) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop(index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva :) , si quieres contenido avanzado te recomiendo mi canal :

[www.youtube.com/diegoveloper](http://www.youtube.com/diegoveloper)